# App Verifier Dll Name unavailable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a C++ Win32 non-managed application that won't run in the debugger.  When Application Verifier is active and all exceptions are enabled I'll get this message in the Output Window of Visual Studio.

```
=======================================
VERIFIER STOP 00000103: pid 0x1778: LoadLibrary is called during DllMain. 

07CDDFE8 : Dll Name (use du to dump).
77820000 : Dll base address.
00000000 : Not used.
00000000 : Not used.
```

Entering `du 07CDDFE8` in the Command Window gives me:

```
>du 07CDDFE8
CXX0013: Error: missing operator
```

Any ideas how to determine what library is the culprit?

Comment: It assumes you are running Windbg and can use the Dump Unicode command.  Well, you're not.  Use Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory1 and put "0x7cddfe8" in the Address box.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Here's what I see: C.:.\.W.i.n.d.o.w.s.\.s.y.s.w.o.w.6.4.\.M.S.C.T.F...d.l.l  I'm not using any web browser control so I'm not sure why that DLL is necessary anyway. Is it possible to determine what needs it?  DependencyWalker shows it's a dependency of my DLL and I get a bunch of errors related to API-MS-WIN-<varies here> DLLs.